# How to detect serie toggle visibility in toast-ui-chart

Tags: toast-ui-chart

I'm trying to save user settings regarding visible or hidden series in a linechart drawn by toast-ui-chart. Does anyone know how i can detect when a user toggle a serie visibility ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using vuejs and @toast-ui/vue-chart (this is my current use case) I found a way by listening on `changeCheckedLegends` which receive a list of boolean values reflecting the visibility setting of each series.

```html
<lineChart :data="chartData" 
  :options="chartOptions" 
  v-on:changeCheckedLegends="changedSelection"
/>
```

Using react and @toast-ui/react-chart you can listen to the same `changeCheckedLegends` event just like this:

```html
<LineChart data={this.state.chartData} 
  options={this.state.chartOptions}
  onChangeCheckedLegends={this.onLegendSelectionChanged}
/>
```

it seems that the original tui-charts lib emit that `changeCheckedLegends` but I haven't enough time to test it furthermore.